# I'm having trouble performing convolutional fusion procedures, about IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Does anyone know the problem

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.spat_feature = spat_model #feature_size =   Nx512x7x7
        self.temp_feature = temp_model #feature_size = Nx512x7x7
        self.layer1       = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv3d(1024, 512, 1, stride=1, padding=1, dilation=1,bias=True),
                                   nn.ReLU(),nn.MaxPool3d(kernel_size=2,stride=2))
        self.fc           = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(8192,2048), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(p=0.85),
                                        nn.Linear(2048, 512), nn.ReLU(), nn.Dropout(p=0.85),
                                        nn.Linear(512, 101))
        
    def forward(self,spat_data,temp_data):
        x1       = self.spat_feature(spat_data)
        x2       = self.temp_feature(temp_data)
        
        y        = torch.cat((x1,x2), dim= 1)
        for i in range(x1.size(1)):
            #y[i] = self.m[i](y[i])
            y[:,(2*i),:,:]   = x1[:,i,:,:] #I have tried to modify four： to two ：
            y[:,(2*i+1)] = x2[:,i,:,:] #I have tried to modify  four： to two：
            
        y        = y.view(y.size(0), 1024, 1, 7, 7)
        cnn_out  = self.layer1(y)
        cnn_out  = cnn_out.view(cnn_out.size(0),-1)
        out      = self.fc(cnn_out)
        return out
```

here is my error:

---

Traceback (most recent call last): File "conv_fusion.py", line 345, in  model = train_model(model, criterion, optimizer,scheduler, num_epochs=20) File "conv_fusion.py", line 167, in train_model outputs = model(spat_data, temp_data) File "/home/el304/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl return forward_call(*input, **kwargs) File "conv_fusion.py", line 263, in forward y[:,(2*i),:,:] = x1[:,i,:,:] IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2

---

＊＊I tried to remove the index value＊＊
RuntimeError: shape '[10, 1024, 1, 7, 7]' is invalid for input of size 2020

Comment: Please show the full error message, including which line it occurs in.

Comment: Can you help me see the error, can't figure out where the error is